# Mock HTTP Requests on the client

Tags: javascript, http, networking, proxy, mocking

I am using a 3rd party JavaScript API library delivered through a CDN.  The library exposes methods that behind the scenes does an HTTP request that I don't have control over.  Is it possible to intercept the HTTP request and alter the response on the client.

For example, let's say the library is a JavaScript math library delivered through a CDN that exposes the variable `mathcdn` with some math functions like `add`:

```
<script src="math.cdn.com"></script>
<script>

var sum = mathcdn.add([4, 4])

</script>
```

If behind the scenes, the `mathcdn.add` method did a HTTP request to a math API to actually compute the sum of the two numbers, could I tell the request to just mock a response?

For example, when the library wants to call `api.com/add?nums[4,5]`, don't actually send the request, but instead mock a response of `{sum: 9}`.

I've seen this when writing tests with `mocks`, but I need to do this on the client.

Comment: Can't you just replace the whole function? For example, `mathcdn.add = function([a, b]) { return {sum: a + b} }`.

Comment: Maybe this is where my example is a bad one.  Internally to the method, there is more logic happening that I cannot control.  I only know that at some point there is a HTTP call that I need to force ignore and replace with a response that I define.  I want to tell the method, 'hey, when you go to make this HTTP request, mock it with my own data and then do whatever else you need to do with it'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, extensions' [`webRequest APIs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest) do allow you to intercept HTTP requests. But I don't think you can do that with normal javascript APIs, since it will cause security issues.

However, you can still accomplish a similar result with some workarounds. For instance, hijack [`window.fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) in the first place.

```
<script>
  // In case you need to use it again.
  const originalFetch = window.fetch

  window.fetch = function(resource, init) {
    // Let some requests act as usual,
    // e.g., requests from other 3rd-party libraries.
    if (...) return originalFetch(resource, init)

    // Extract the information you need,
    // e.g., query string in the url,
    // and create the corresponding result.
    const result = ...

    // Wrap the result in a Response object,
    // which is how the original fetch returns it.
    // So it won't break the library's following code.
    return new Response(result)
  }
</script>

<script src="math.cdn.com"></script>
```

### Limitations

- If you don't know how the library makes its HTTP requests, you may have to replace all possible functions and classes, e.g., traditional [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).
- Generally you can't load the library asynchronously, i.e., script with `async` attribute, because the execution order will become unpredictable, and the library may store a reference to `window.fetch()` before you replace it.

Comment: This is great!  Although the API in question is obfuscated, I do believe I can trace down the method by which the request is being made.  I haven't tried this yet, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.  Thanks for the detailed response.